# Create a "COMMON" confimation dialogue - possible approaches and best practices

Tags: angularjs

I have an application based on the presentation of one or more tabs. Each tab type identifies a specific activity (e.g. create an object of a specific type, like user, user profile, etc.).

Any tab type can concurrently appear one or more times at any given moment (e.g. two or more Create User tabs can be open at the same time).

For those tabs that accept inputs like the examples above, I would like to build a **common** "Close Confirmation Dialogue" mechanism that would be popped every time the user attempts to close a tab before saving the data while the data of the tab had been changed.

I did some tests that work OK under **sterilized** conditions, but when testing basic combinations the behavior begins to become strange.

The dialogue would need to return an indication of what the user selected (e.g. "Proceed with Tab Close" or "Cancel Tab Close request").

I was thinking about creating a service that would handle this, but I'm not sure if the use of a callback function (passed to the service from the tab's controller) would be suitable to return to the tab controller the selection of the user.

If possible, I am keen to find some examples on how this should be done.

Comment: such questions are that good, but usual way to go here is to return promise from service. So from component it looks like ~ service.showConfirm('Are you sure').then(closeFunction, doingNothingFuction)

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, I didn't think about promises. Will give it a try. Thanks for your suggestion!!!!